# How to properly use TS to return an object with a specific list of properties

Tags: typescript

In order to aid type checking after returning data from a generic function, I'm trying to set it up so that the return object only has itemIDs which I passed to the function. However, I cannot figure out how to initialize my return object properly.

I can use simply {} if I make the properties optional, but they are all going to come back and I don't want to do that. When I use a for loop, TS is happy. But nearly the same approach to initialize "newObj" is not working as it is treating the property as just a string and not T in this context. What am I missing? What approach could work here without making [Property in T] optional?

So while I'm trying to get TS to show a return type of:
<{item1: boolean; item2: boolean; item3: boolean;}>

I'm only able to get this without errors:
<{item1?: boolean | undefined; item2?: boolean | undefined; item3?: boolean | undefined;}>

Thank you for any help!

````
const testObj = [
    { itemID: 'item1', val: 34 },
    { itemID: 'item2', val: 45 },
    { itemID: 'item3', val: 200 },
] as const;

testChoices(testObj);


export function testChoices<T extends string>(items: readonly { itemID: T; val: number }[]) {
    const newObj: { [Property in T]: boolean } = { [items[0].itemID]: items[0].val > 100 } ; 
    // TS error: Type '{ [x: string]: boolean; }' is not assignable to type '{ [Property in T]: boolean; }'

    for (const item of items) {
        newObj[item.itemID] = item.val > 100; // ok
    }

    return newObj;
}```
````

Comment: Will `const newObj = { } as { [Property in T]: boolean };` work for you?

Comment: computed property always infered as `{[prop:string]:any type}`

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova That type assertion is perfect, thank you! I'm fine with the function not flagging some errors, as I know I've got that right and where I want help is in the use of the function externally.